# Seeking location data for UK parliamentary constituencies

Tags: geospatial, uk, elections, politics

I'm trying to do some data analysis on crime rates within my local constituency. I'm using the UK Police API to get the data but currently, I have to manually define the boundary using longitude and latitude coordinates defining a polynomial.

Is there any way to download the outline of UK constituencies as longitude and latitude coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ONS has what looks like the data you're looking for - [digital vector boundaries for Westminster Parliamentary Constituencies in the UK](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/5ce27b980ffb43c39b012c2ebeab92c0_2), as at 31 December 2017.

Comment: Is there anyway to compress the geospatial data as the API gives a URI too long error?

Comment: @Tasty213 no idea, sorry